# Sql query day check

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database named shop and a table named orders with these columns:

```
`id(INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`)
`value(INT(30))`
`order_date(DATE)`
```

I want to create an SQL query to select only the orders placed Friday and Monday with a value larger then 100.

Comment: can you delete 'php' tag? ;) your question is about sql

Comment: ok i deleted the php tag :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [DAYOFWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

```
select * from orders
where value > 100
and DAYOFWEEK(order_date) in (2,6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select * from table
where dayname(order_date) in ('friday','monday') and value>100
```

Comment: better to use `DAYOFWEEK` function.

Comment: i used the dayofweek function thank you for help guys

Answer (score 1):

use the `DAYOFWEEK` function.

```
SELECT ID, VALUE, ORDER_DATE
FROM orders
WHERE value > 100
AND DAYOFWEEK(order_date) IN (2,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below query,

```
SELECT * from `orders` where value > 100 and DAYOFWEEK(order_date) in (2,6);
```

If you want to change day, only change (2,6).
as Sunday= 1,Monday=2.....,Sat=7.